# How can I access objects in the Running Object Table (ROT) from within Internet Explorer's Protected Mode?

Tags: internet-explorer, com, winapi

I have tried the following:

- Setting `HKLM\Software\Classes\AppID\{AppID}\ROTFlags` to `0x1` (as recommended [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679687%28VS.85%29.aspx))
- Registering the object in the ROT with the `ROTFLAGS_ALLOWANYCLIENT` flag set.

However, I always get a `0x800401e3 (Operation unavailable)` error whenever I try to access the ROT object from within IE's protected mode.

Comment: What API gives you this error, GetActiveObject?